# can we have a double function pointer in C?

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

I am wondering that unlike the double pointers `(int**)` , can we have double function pointer?

I mean the function pointer pointing to the address of the another function pointer ?

I want something like

```
int add(int A , int B){
    return A+B;
}

int main(void){

    int (*funcpointerToAdd)(int,int) = add; // single function pointer pointing to the function add
    printf("%d \n",funcpointerToAdd(2,3));
  

    int (**doubleFuncPointerToAdd)(int,int) = &funcpointerToAdd;
    printf("%d \n",doubleFuncPointerToAdd(2,3));

    return 0;
}
```

but this gives me an error `called object ‘doubleFuncPointerToAdd’ is not a function or function pointer`

is this possible to do this thing anyway ?

Comment: If you fix your code, yes, you can. `(*doubleFuncPointerToAdd)(2,3)` . But fair warning, the lifetime is now bound to the viability of `funcpointerToAdd`, so whilst amusing, I'm pressed to consider a place I would use such a thing.

Comment: @WhozCraig, it could be used for implementing closures in C. I've made a post about it on Reddit. See https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/s99jej/a_new_design_pattern_for_implementing_capturing/

Comment: Consider typedefing function type. It will make the code more readable: `typedef int fun_t(int,int); fun_t* funcpointerToAdd=add; fun_t** doubleFuncPointerToAdd = &funcpointerToAdd`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use pointers to pointers to functions, but you have to deference them once first:

```
int add(int A , int B){
    return A+B;
}

int main(void){

    int (*funcpointerToAdd)(int,int) = &add;
//By the way, it is a POINTER to a function, so you need to add the ampersand
//to get its location in memory. In c++ it is implied for functions, but
//you should still use it.
    printf("%d \n",funcpointerToAdd(2,3));
  

    int (**doubleFuncPointerToAdd)(int,int) = &funcpointerToAdd;
    printf("%d \n",(*doubleFuncPointerToAdd)(2,3));
//You need to dereference the double pointer,
//to turn it into a normal pointer, which you can then call

    return 0;
}
```

This is also true for other types:

```
struct whatever {
   int a;
};

int main() {
   whatever s;
   s.a = 15;
   printf("%d\n",s.a);
   whatever* p1 = &s;
   printf("%d\n",p1->a); //OK
//x->y is just a shortcut for (*x).y
   whatever** p2 = &p1;
   printf("%d\n",p2->a); //ERROR, trying to get value (*p2).a,
//which is a double pointer, so it's equivalent to p1.a
   printf("%d\n",(*p2)->a); //OK
}
```

Comment: thanks, this has answered my question very well

Comment: can we use a normal pointer to store the address of the function pointer ? although it seems tough as the function pointer has the return type and arguments are associated with it. But just a query

Comment: A double pointer to a function, is a pointer to a pointer to a function. (I don't think I understood your question...)

Comment: like in my question, can I create one normal int** p for storing the address of the funcpointerToAdd ?

Comment: You need to understand what a pointer is:
A pointer is just a location in memory, where other data is (maybe) stored. When you add an asterisk at the end of a name of a type, that means that you don't want to store the object itself, but rather the location in memory of such an object.
When you say int**, you mean pointer to an int, and a int* is a pointer to an int. So, a int** is the location in memory, of an int* pointer.

Comment: You asked if you could create a "normal pointer in**". That is not a normal pointer, that is a double pointer to an int. Nevertheless, you different pointer types can be used interchangeably, so long as you don't derefernce them: You could have
```
void whatever() {}
int** a;
void (*functionPointer)() = &whatever;
a = (int**)&functionPointer;
```
This code is ok, as long as you don't try to read **a as an int.

Finally, the closest thing to a "normal pointer" c has, is the void* pointer. It is the location of _something_ in memory.

Comment: You cannot dereference it, and you need to cast to some other pointer type before you can use it.